# В диалоговом окне, создать кнопку скопировать в буфер

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет. Программа выводит числа из указанного диапазона. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать кнопку, которая будет копировать в буфер обмена текст из вывода.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def display():
    messagebox.showinfo("Output", str(list(range(X.get(), Y.get() + 1))))


root = Tk()
root.title("Aboba")
root.geometry("400x300+760+300")

X = IntVar()
Y = IntVar()

Xstart = Label(text="Start:")
Yfinish = Label(text="Finish:")

Xstart.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w")
Yfinish.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w")

X_entry = Entry(textvariable=X)
Y_entry = Entry(textvariable=Y)

X_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
Y_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

message_button = Button(text="Output", command=display)
message_button.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проще сохранить результат в переменную, потом добавить его в буфер обмена, и вывести его же через диалоговое окно:

```
def display():
    result = str(list(range(X.get(), Y.get() + 1)))
    root.clipboard_clear()  # Очистить буфер обмена
    root.clipboard_append(result)  # Добавить результат в буфер обмена
    messagebox.showinfo("Output", result)
```

Comment: Ну можно и так конечно. Спасибо за помощь